# how to get the value from codeigniter to ajax?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i have an ajax which I don't know if it is correct. I want to get the value from the controller and pass it to ajax.

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: swoosh(id, path+'swoosh_employee/swoosh_delete_child', 'childdv'),
    success: function(response) {
      if (response != "Error")
        { 
            $('#success-delete').modal('show');
        } 
        else 
        { 
        alert("Error"); 
        }
    }
  });
 event.preventDefault();
```

and in the controller:

```
 public function swoosh_delete_child()
{
    $P1 = $this->session->userdata('id');
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
    $id = $_GET['h'];

    $response = $this->emp->delete_children($id);
}
```

model

```
public function delete_chilren($id){
.......//codes here.. etc. etc.
if success // 
 return "success";
else
 return "Error";
}
```

i just want to pass/get the value of $reponse and pass it to the ajax and check if the value is error or not..

Comment: I just want to get the message to alert if i successfully deleted a row from database.

Comment: and i dont know if my ajax code is correct or what. just want to get the message.

Comment: what does `swoosh(id, path+'swoosh_employee/swoosh_delete_child', 'childdv'),` do? what does it return? json or text?

Comment: my swoosh is a function ....
function swoosh(data,url,dbox)
{ 
xmlHttp5=SUB4GetXmlHttpObject()
if (xmlHttp5==null)
{
alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
return
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller:

you should have something like this

```
public function swoosh_delete_child(){

$P1 = $this->session->userdata('id');
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
$id = $_GET['h'];

$response['status'] = $this->emp->delete_children($id);
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

then in your ajax, to access the response

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url: swoosh(id, path+'swoosh_employee/swoosh_delete_child', 'childdv'),,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response){
  if (response.status)
    { 
        $('#success-delete').modal('show');
    } 
    else 
    { 
    alert("Error"); 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: can i alert the value of response.status? like alert(response.status)?

Comment: There is no reason to JSON encode it, its just a simple string.

Comment: @jah that's not a good habit it's an event. Boolean should always be boolean , unless if you want to have a `status == 'true'`?

Comment: I would say it's bad habbit to encode something that doesn't need it. First you encode it, and then javascript has to parse the JSON.

Comment: And his model does not return a boolean, it returns a string!

Comment: No that's not a bad habit that's what you correct , so tell me what do you proposed? just being lame is a bad habit. He can adjust on what's right , sooner you'll understand what I mean. So don't argue here if you want to learn ,learn to accept other answer

Comment: @jah btw do you develop in codeigniter? I think you should know what is the ideal datatype that returns in model it's either array or boolean.

Comment: I used to yes, but that has nothing to with it. But if you look at his model it cleary returns a string of either "success" or "Error", not a boolean. There is no reason to get mad, i'm just saying that he doesn't have to json encode it, he can just echo it as it is.

Comment: I have to agree with Drixson it's a better practice to use JSON, XML or some other more structured format over just sending strings.

Comment: im just getting the echo of "echo json_encode($response);".. my alerts are not working. :(

Comment: it's working now. but. when i alert the response. the alert are "HTML TAGS". what is happening :)) ahaha

Answer (score 2):

Just echo in the controller:

```
$response = $this->emp->delete_children($id);
```

And `alert` the response:

```
alert(response); //output: success / Error
```

Comment: but when i echo in the controller. it just echo on the page :(